# Can I change the size and/or location of the notification balloon?

Tags: windows-7, notifications

I have another developer team that is considering the move to windows 7. They want to keep the notification balloon popping up in the center of the screen. How can we change the size or location of notification balloons? say for outlook emails, etc...

Comment: I don't think this is a qw worth answering (I have been wrong before). There HAS to be that. This problem has been already solved MANY MANY times before. but in different ways than yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the notification balloon.  That was one of the goals of the notification balloon system. If you want to move the balloon or change the size, you shouldn't be using a balloon.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx#howlong

> Ideally, users immersed in their work won't see your notifications at all. Rather, they'll see your notifications only when their flow is already broken.
>
> #### Notifications must be ignorable
>
> Notifications don't require immediate user action and users can freely ignore them.
>
> **Developers and designers often want to present their notifications in a way that users can't ignore. This goal completely undermines the primary benefit of notifications because it would break users' flow. If users are distracted by your notifications or feel obligated to read them, your notification design has failed.**